# Using multiple handle_path

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I created the first handle_path and it worked, API A received the requests made to `/apia/v1`, as expected.

However, I have two APIs, A and B, and I need to route the messages that arrive at `/apia*` to the service running on port 3001 and the requests that arrive at `/apib*` to the service running on port 3002.

But when I added the second service, all requests are going to it. Below is what I tried but it didn't work.

What did I do wrong?

```
:8000 {
    handle_path /apia* {
        rewrite * /apia{uri}
        reverse_proxy localhost:3001
    }
    handle_path /apib* {
        rewrite * /apib{uri}
        reverse_proxy localhost:3002
    }
}
```

EDIT: My second try, same result.

```
localhost

reverse_proxy /apia/* localhost:3001
reverse_proxy /apib/* localhost:3002
```